# Changing the position of panel titles

Tags: plotting, labeling

I am trying to plot three panels side-by-side with

```
Partition[
  Table[
    Panel[panellist[[i]], 
      Style[CharacterRange["A", "C"][[i]], 17], {{Left, Top}}, 
      Background -> White, FrameMargins -> 0, ImageMargins -> 10, 
      ImageSize -> {300, 300}, Appearance -> Frameless], 
    {i, 1, 3}], 
  3]
```

where `panellist` is a list of 3 plots. I want to include reference letters (A-C), but the alignment `{Left,Top}` ends up placing the letter too much to the left. How can I give explicit coordinates here?

Comment: can you try if  replacing `ImageMargins->10` with `FrameMargins -> {{-10, 10}, {10, -5}}` give what you need?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of many ways to accomplish what I think you want. For what it lacks in elegance, it makes up with simplicity.

```
panellist = Table[Plot[Sin[2 Pi i x], {x, 0, 1}], {i, 3}];
labels = Style["     " <> #, 17] & /@ {"A", "B", "C"};
Row[
  Table[
    Column[{
      labels[[i]],
      Panel[panellist[[i]],
        Background -> White,
        FrameMargins -> 0,
        ImageMargins -> 10,
        ImageSize -> {300, 200},
        Appearance -> Frameless]}],
    {i, 3}]]
```

[image: plots]

You can shift the characters in the labels by adding or subtracting spaces in the 1st argument of the `Style` expression used in `labels`.

#### Edit

If you would prefer to have the labels inside the panels, that can be accommodated with this variant:

```
labels = Style["       " <> #, 16] & /@ {"A", "B", "C"};
Row[
  Table[
    Panel[Column[{labels[[i]], panellist[[i]]}],
      Background -> White,
      FrameMargins -> 0,
      ImageMargins -> 5,
      ImageSize -> 200],
  {i, 3}]]
```

[image: plots]

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the labels in `Pane` and use `ImageMargins` with a negative value for the right margin:

```
panellist = Plot[Sin[# x], {x, -Pi, Pi}] & /@ Range[3];
Table[Panel[panellist[[i]], 
   Pane[Style[CharacterRange["A", "C"][[i]], 17], 
       Alignment -> {Center, Right}, ImageSize -> {50, Full},
       ImageMargins -> {{0, -35}, {0, 10}}], 
   {{Left, Top}}, 
   Background -> White, FrameMargins -> 0, ImageMargins -> 10, 
   ImageSize -> {300, 300}, Appearance -> Frameless], {i, 1, 3}]
```

[image]